# Unable to reach breakpoint in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, wxwidgets, breakpoints

I am facing a odd behavior of Breakpoints in Visual Studio 2010 Express. Below is the code with breakpoints.

[image]

I am able to break at the first breakpoint (Line 159), but stepping after line 160, the cursor vanishes, i.e after this image of code pressing F10/F11 the application is displayed.

The problem is,

Why isn't line 162 executing (Without this statement, `asserts` fail elsewhere) or breaking at it?

Note : The line 166 `Refresh();` is being executed, because the application displayed is updated.

**EDIT :** On suggestions in comments, I stepped through disassembly, and I found this line (from **wxWidgets** library) is causing the debug to fail `00D5AF7C  call        wxCharBuffer::~wxCharBuffer (0D207AAh)`

Comment: If the code is compiled in Release mode, the line in question could be optimized out. Try compiling the code in Debug mode.

Comment: This is obviously a heap/stack frame corruption problem

Comment: @PhillipNgan:I am already compiling in Debug mode.

Comment: Check that the /Od compiler is present. This disables code  optimization.

Comment: Have you changed the code since last build, or since you started debugging? Have you tried a rebuild-all?

Comment: @PhillipNgan: Yeah, Optimization is disabled.

Comment: Do full rebuild first. That helps 99% of time. Then, start commenting out memory modifying lines

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Since last build I only added line 162. And on your suggestion, tried Rebuild solution. But no help :(

Comment: Have you tried stepping through disassembly? With combined assembly-source view you can tell what exactly is going on.

Comment: @gwiazdorrr: How do I start stepping through assembly code? As in from first breakpoint.

Comment: Once you hit a breakpoint go to Debug->Windows->Disassembly. Or just click RMB and then "Go to disassembly".

Comment: @gwiazdorrr: Thanks, that was convenient! I have rounded on to a assembly line, after which the havoc wreaked :D.

Comment: @gwiazdorrr: Disassembly helped solve my problem, i got rid of `wxCharBuffer`. You should consider adding your comment as answer. :)

Comment: @VinayakGarg you got your answer already but just as an FYI, I sometimes find deleting bin, obj directories then full rebuild resolves this error

Comment: @Dr.AndrewBurnett-Thompson: Thanks, I will remember. BTW i have used this method when installing packages in Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried stepping through disassembly? With combined assembly-source view you can tell what exactly is going on.

To do that once you hit a breakpoint go to Debug->Windows->Disassembly. Or just click RMB and then "Go to disassembly".